# Angular 4 HttpClient Error response json to array

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have been building a project in Angular for the past few months.

I had been catching any API errors by using the second param of the .subscribe method.

My server would send back a JSON string with the errors in. But today this has all stopped working.

if I access 'err.error' I just get a string, instead of the array that I have been used to. Nothing has changed on client or server side on my development environment.

And I have even rolled back a few commits to see, but nothing. All of my forms have stopped working now.

Can anyone point me in a direction to look at next.

I am using Angular 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Can you restructure the error callback somewhat like this:

```
(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  if (err.error instanceof Error) {
    console.log("Client-side error occured.");
  } else {
    console.log("Server-side error occured.");
  }
}
```

You'll need to import HttpErrorResponse from @angular/common/http but it should be a bit more informative with console.log on 'err'.

Comment: This is my code I have now 

`
  register() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:4003/api/testapi').subscribe(res =>{}, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        console.log("Client-side error occured.");
      } else {
        console.log("Server-side error occured.", err);
      }
    })
  }
`

And this is my API that is built in Laravel 

`
Route::get('testapi', function () {
    return response()->json(['Error' => 'This is the error'], 500);
});
`

Comment: What does 'err' look like? anything in there you can use?

Comment: err is a object with 'error' in it and this is currently a json string. But yesterday it was a json object